# Execute two commands as a single action in windows command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-console

We have a system where an application A starts the second application B  to run in background (no gui or console window should be shown). However, the first application should be able to execute a command and continue working without waiting for the second one to finish. After B has finished, an empty file is created to indicate this to application A. This is the requirement because this system is built so that it can run on both Windows and Linux machines as well as clusters and therefore the file cannot be directly created by application B.

Here is the equivalent Linux command issued by application A:

```
{ B; touch done.txt; } &
```

The question is how to produce the same effect in Windows?

Comment: Have a look at the `start` command...Good luck!